# Email validation changed upgrading from grails 2.0.0 to 2.4.3

Tags: grails, email-validation

My project recently upgraded grails from 2.0.0 to 2.4.3.  In a domain object I am using the email validation constraint.  I've noticed in testing that emails with fake tlds eg 'fake@fakedomain.tld' are now considered invalid.  Grails documentation says it is using Apache Commons EmailValidation class to do the validating.  That documentation explicitly states that it [doesn't check for valid tlds](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html).

Has anyone else seen this issue, and if so was there a simple work around?  I am on the fence between a custom validator that allows invalid tlds or removing the constraint all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the new Commons Vaidator v1.4.0 which is used by Grails v2.4.3 has an open bug [VALIDATOR-338](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VALIDATOR-338) where unknown TLDs in e-mail addresses are invalid. This only effects 1.4 and not 1.3.1 which Grails 2.0.0 used.

The quickest route would be to implement a custom validator for now. You might even get away with using a custom regular expression (of which there are many [examples](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) of).

Comment: Custom validator it is until the bug is resolved.  Thanks much.